# Sync Framework, how to download from a read only database view?

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

My Server Provision (source) is a read only database, how can I download/sync from it to another database without needing the synchronization tables?

Also the read only have another table schema called DW_Gen while the client which is the destination have dbo. By the way the read only table is a view.

I got full access to the destination database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Fx needs to track the changes on the source database. the older provider can use SQL Change Tracking, the newer ones uses its own change tracking tables. without the change tracking, it wont know what has changed.